# Typescript or operator doesn't work when passing as a generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following setup:

```
const foo = async <T>(a): Promise<T> => {
  return await a // call server here
}

type A = { bar: 'bar' } | { baz: 'baz' }
foo<A>({ bar: 'bar' })
  .then(response => {
    // error: property bar doesn't exist on type { baz: 'baz' }
    if (response.bar) console.log('bar') 

    // error: property baz doesn't exist on type { bar: 'bar' }
    if (response.baz) console.log('baz')
  })
```

Is this a bug in typescript or my setup is wrong?

Comment: That seems to be working just fine, what did you expect to happen? I'd suggest reading e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html, the promise and generic type aren't relevant here.

Comment: Why would this be related to generics? Or be a bug? Or somehow wrong? [Here is code without generics that works the same way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3nNAHVaIAXPAN7wBGsJA5FTDfAL7wA+ZlUAXrVV40wDcAKGEB6MfBAwYSGCVyzc0jAE9OMeMCQg0KGlhAAPAJaZ4qeGuUc+vbgOEmAZvAAUOfOhAA6egEpEAiQIXwgkAHM3OlgaQNEJKRk5BSUVdT4tHT0DKVNzS2sEcnp7BmYnVw9dL0I-bkDkdBCwyOi+OKA). It works as it should - properties from the union that don't overlap cannot be addressed directly. What made you expect the opposite?

Comment: `if ('bar' in response) console.log('bar') `

Comment: @Keith if you make an answer out of your comment with a bit more detail I'll accept. thanks!

Comment: @goldylucks  Ok, done.  Hopefully my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Typescript doesn't narrow types down when doing a simple truefy test on a property.. `if (foo.bar) {}`.  I believe this is because properties in JavaScript can be dynamic, eg. property getters / proxy's etc / return 0 / false / null etc.  IOW: `if (obj.prop)` has more meanings than does this property exist.

Luckily JavaScript does have a special keyword called `in`, that specifically checks if a property exists on an object.

So if you do `if ('bar' in foo)`, Typescript can be pretty certain that it can now narrow down the type for `bar`.

So in your example

```
if ('bar' in response) console.log('bar')
```

will not error, but better still `response` will now also have a property called bar.

```
if (`bar` in response) console.log(response.bar)
```

In a good editor, when typing `response` inside that `console.log(` the editor will also give `bar` as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this situation with ***type assertion*** :

```
const foo = async <T>(a): Promise<T> => {
    return await a // call server here
}

type Bar = { bar: 'bar' }
type Baz = { baz: 'baz' }
type A = Bar | Baz

foo<A>({ bar: 'bar' })
    .then(response => {
        if ((response as Bar).bar) console.log('bar')
        if ((response as Baz).baz) console.log('baz')
    })
```

But I really do not recommend it, if you are abstracting this from more complex example here what I suggest you to do:

```
type Bar = { type: 'bar', bar: 'bar' }
type Baz = { type: 'baz', baz: 'baz' }
type A = Bar | Baz

foo<A>({ bar: 'bar' })
    .then(response => {
        switch (response.type) {
            case 'bar':
                console.log(response.bar)
                break;
            case 'baz':
                console.log(response.baz)
                break;
            default:
                console.log('unknown type')
        }
    })
```